# In Woocommerce for Unisex Product: How can I Show A Different Image Based on Men Or Women Category Selection

Tags: image, woocommerce, product, display

Many of my products are unisex, how can I display my male mockup images for unisex products listed within the "Men's T-Shirts" category and vice versa for women? Ideally the image would be pulled from the image gallery of the product so the male & female image would be the the 2nd & 3rd image within the product image gallery.

I found a code that allows for displaying different images from the shop page vs the single product page but I can't seem to figure out the code to base it on a "if within cateogry" calling. This is the code:
`add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'remove_featured_image', 10, 2); function remove_featured_image($html, $attachment_id ) { global $post, $product; $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); if ( $attachment_id == $featured_image ) $html = ''; return $html; }`

And was playing with this code to select the image from the gallery:
`$attachment_id = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids()[0]; echo "<img src='" . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ) . "'>";`

I'm not sure if I'm playing with the right code. I would appreciate any help.

- Jane

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple, no code solution.
Create a separate products for men and women, then use a plugin like: https://www.wooextend.com/product/group-stock-manager-shared-stock-woocommerce/

to connect both products so they share the same stock. This way you can add separate images and categories but when "men" product is bought, the stock of "women" product will decrease too. Very simple and effective.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I really don't want to double up on products and increase my database size & resources. I have hundreds of products. I also try to avoid plugins where possible. I will hold this option as a possible last resort. Thank you again. Happy Holidays!